# Heroku push rejected, Ruby Version Changed Detected, Could not find net-scp-1.0.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, heroku

I can't figure out what is going on here. I deployed to Heroku on Tuesday with no problem. I have not changed my Ruby version locally or on the Gemfile but heroku is telling me that I have changed Ruby Versions & it's unable to find net-scp-1.0.6. Everything works perfectly locally, I have search around and can't find anything addressing a similar problem.

```
Counting objects: 81, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (62/62), done.
Writing objects: 100% (62/62), 10.77 KiB, done.
Total 62 (delta 49), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Deleting 8 files matching .slugignore patterns.
-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.0.pre.5
       Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
       Old: ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-linux]
       New: ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Could not find net-scp-1.0.6 in any of the sources
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

This is what my Gemfile looks like.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.11'

gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

gem 'pg'
gem 'thin'
gem 'best_in_place'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'coffeebeans'
gem 'mail'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'carmen'
gem 'haml'
gem 'devise'
gem 'sinatra', '~> 1.3.2'
gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'fog', '~> 1.3.1'
gem 'wicked'
gem 'lazy_high_charts', '~> 1.1.5'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'
gem 'sass-rails'

group :assets do
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
end

group :test, :development do
  gem 'hirb'
end
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The net-scp-1.0.6 gem was yanked recently.

Locally, run:

```
gem cleanup  
bundle update
```

Then commit and push, it will update net-scp to the latest version and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured it out. I had tried running bundle update locally but had no luck. Once I forced net-scp 1.0.4 and run bundle update things were back in action.

Comment: There's a new version. Try: gem cleanup then bundle update/install

Comment: @mc6688 - your gem cleanup then bundle update/install solution worked for me. Thanks! :-)

Comment: The bundle install is superfluous here :) (Works great though.)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like I figured this out. This issue was caused by net-scp being yanked from Ruby Gems due to security concerns. I followed the instructions on this Fog issue (https://github.com/fog/fog/issues/1561) and locked net-scp down to 1.0.4 and life is back in order.