# Error with bundle install --deployment --without development test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundle

I am in trouble
When I write this command `bundle install --deployment --without development test`
the command return me this and I don´t know how I can do.

> Could not find net-scp-1.0.6 in any of the sources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is `Could not find net-scp-1.0.6 in any of the sources`

There is an apparent fix here: [Heroku push rejected, Ruby Version Changed Detected, Could not find net-scp-1.0.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033607/heroku-push-rejected-ruby-version-changed-detected-could-not-find-net-scp-1-0)