# Deploying on Heroku, how to specify ruby version to use for bundler?

Tags: ruby, heroku, bundler, gemfile, heroku-toolbelt

Something has changed recently on Heroku. I can't deploy my app as I've done before:

```
me@host my-project (master) $ git push staging master
Counting objects: 52, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (51/51), done.
Writing objects: 100% (52/52), 159.47 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 52 (delta 42), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Deleting 4 files matching .slugignore patterns.
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.13.6
remote:        Your app was upgraded to bundler 1.13.6.
remote:        Previously you had a successful deploy with bundler 1.11.2.
remote:        
remote:        If you see problems related to the bundler version please refer to:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version
remote:        Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
remote:        Old: ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]
remote:        New: ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.0
remote:        Bundler Output: Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.0
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: ! Push rejected to my-project-staging.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/my-project-staging.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/my-project-staging.git'
```

I don't get it, i'm using `ruby 2.2.0` since the beginning:

```
me@host my-project (master) $ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]

me@host my-project (master) $ cat .ruby-version 
2.2.0

me@host my-project (master) $ cat Gemfile | grep 'ruby'
ruby '2.2.0'
```

I don't know how to tell bundler I'm still using ruby 2.2.0. My bundler have this in the bottom:

```
RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.3.0p0

BUNDLED WITH
   1.12.1
```

---

Why bundler doesn't use the ruby 2.2.0 version? It's using 2.3.0 instead...

Comment: Do you say so in your Gemfile? I mean, do you have a line **`ruby '2.2.0'`** saying it explicitly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku push rejected, Ruby Version Changed Detected, Could not find net-scp-1.0.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033607/heroku-push-rejected-ruby-version-changed-detected-could-not-find-net-scp-1-0)

Comment: @EddeAlmeida Sure, the result of `$ cat Gemfile | grep 'ruby'` is `ruby '2.2.0'`.

Comment: @lcguida No, unfortunately it is not. I think it is more `bundler` related.

Comment: Could you run `heroku run --app <you_app_name> bundle env` and see what ruby version is bundle configured with? Something like: `Running bundle env on ⬢ behive-sga... up, run.3159 (Free)
Bundler 1.6.3
Ruby 2.1.1 (2014-02-24 patchlevel 76) [x86_64-linux]
Rubygems 2.2.2`

Answer (score 3):

Check your `Gemfile.lock`. Recent versions of bundler add both the ruby version and bundler version that were used install the gems (and generate the Gemfile.lock).

At the bottom you'll find:

```
RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.3.0 

BUNDLED WITH
   1.13.1 # or whatever version of bundler you're using
```

Remove this, and re-run `bundle install` with the correct version of ruby - you may need to remove + re-add a gem to trigger a re-build of the Gemfile.lock file.

Comment: I've done this but it always 2.3.0 ruby version. I don't get it, I've specified 2.2.0 everywhere.

Comment: Are you using a ruby version manager? Make sure you're running `bundle install` with ruby 2.2.0. If you're using `rvm`, run `rvm use 2.2` before running `bundle`.

Comment: Indeed, I'm using `rbenv`, but as I've pasted in my post, the local version of ruby I'm using is 2.2.0

Answer (score 1):

Finally I add to remove bundler and install the same version as Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes bundler doesn't generate in Gemfile.lock

```
RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.x.x
```

In that case, just add that entry manually  inside the Gemfile.lock file commit and push it to master. Heroku will take that version and build.